# Why wont a MUI component be hidden by setting display to none in the sx prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a responsive side drawer with MUI's `Drawer` component in React. I'm using MUI version 4.12.1.

On the [mui.com example](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer) they use the `sx` prop and pass in an object with display set to some different screen-width dependant values.

However, when I use this code in an `App.js` file:

```
<Drawer
  variant="permanent"
  sx={{
    display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'none' },
  }}
  open
>
  Hello There
</Drawer>
```

The drawer still shows up. It also shows up when I simply set `display: 'none'`

Why is this? How can I actually create a drawer like this with something like `sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}` that hides the drawer at smaller screen sizes?

Comment: What's the material-ui version are you using?

Comment: @NearHuscarl 4.12.1
oh do I just need to update to version 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MUI v4, this is done with the [`Hidden` component](https://v4.mui.com/components/hidden)

As NearHuscarl said, the `sx` prop is only available in MUI v5.

So to hide your drawer for sm and smaller, you'd probably want something like this:

```
<Hidden smDown implementation="css">
    <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      open
    >
      Hello There
    </Drawer>
</Hidden>
```

Comment: Note that Hidden component is deprecated in v5, `This component is deprecated because its functionality can be created with the sx prop or the useMediaQuery hook.`

Answer (score 1):

`sx` prop is only available in MUI v5, please upgrade MUI to the latest version. You can see the [installation guide](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm) here for more detail.